# htaccess hide url ?code= and read it from php file

Tags: .htaccess

i want a change the .htaccess file to hide the url parameters . 
I would like to accept urls like
http://www.demo.com/74874 , that means http://www.demo.com?code=74874

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what operating system you are using and instruction can vary, plus you didn't say if your are using HTTPD and if mod_rewrite is already installed/enabled. Assuming mod_rewrite is enabled and `AllowOverride FileInfo` is set in the server config, you could use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+) ?code=$1
```

This will accept any number as the path and rewrite it with the query string. If you want to keep any existing query string parameters, you would need to add `[QSA]` to the end of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . The urls http://demo.com/?code=123 and http://demo.com/?123 works . But the url http://demo.com/123 dosnt work

Comment: Can you confirm the `.htaccess` is actually being read by the server? What version of HTTPD?